# (How) Can I try out the new C# 9.0 language features?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

At the moment I am porting a certain project of mine to net5.0. I would like to try out the new C# language feature as well. My project files now looks like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
  (removed for brevity)
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

An example of the code I am trying to compile and the related compiler error messages:
[image]

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.7.0 Preview 2.0
- .NET SDK version : 5.0.100-preview.4.20258.7

This does not seems to be enough. Are there any additional things I need to do?

Thanks in advance for your kind response

Comment: What is the error message you get when you try to compile (or run) it?

Comment: I actually don't get an error message when compiling without specific C#9.0 features. But when I for instance try to use the records feature it does not compile:

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you are using and the complete error message you get when you compile the source code.

Comment: If it doesn't compile then presumably it gives you some information about why? Please tell us specifically what happens

Comment: C# 9 will be released in November. Why do you expect the new features for now? https://sharplab.io/ allows to switch for C#9 specific branches from roslyn repo

Comment: [Feature status](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md) shows that records feature still in progress

Comment: Usually there are some preview releases that you can try out. The blog post https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/ seems to suggest to me this is the case, though not named explicitly

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that it is not possible yet (at least not with current preview bits).

I found the answer in the comments in this blog post : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#comment-6128

There is no ETA (yet)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same also.

Some of the new C# 9 features are working (target typed new), but the no-go for "init" or "data classes".